# isSpeakerPhoneOn = true makes remoteParticipant hear his own voice android webRtc

Tags: android, webrtc, android-audiomanager, speaker

In my application i have created a video call with webRTC protocol. Inside the onCreate method i set the speaker value true so the user can hear the audio from speaker. i do this using the AudioManager system service from Android.

`audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true`

However the remote user hears his own voice. Is there any other or proper way to set up the speaker so that the user can hear the voice as it supposed to?

Comment: Which webRTC library are you using? Is it inside a webView?

Comment: implementation "org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006"